# Missing seed functions to create reproducible RL experiments with Open AI Gym and PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am using a simple DDQN-PER (https://github.com/higgsfield/RL-Adventure/blob/master/4.prioritized%20dqn.ipynb) to run my RL experiments. This could be used as a minimal and verifiable code for my question.

Also, here are the seed functions that I have found to be useful -

```
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
env.seed(seed)
env.action_space.seed(seed)
```

Despite this, I cannot reproduce my experiments. I believe I am missing some seed function and will appreciate inputs on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you gym Version. There has been a major recent upgrade with v0.20 .

[Here is also a blog post](https://brosa.ca/blog/ale-release-v0.7), describing that the new environments should be deterministic, quoting the essence:

> Determinism
>
> Up until now, the ALE hasn’t been completely deterministic. There
> exist games that implement their own PRNG seeded by various methods
> which depend on the console’s state. We now properly control for this
> source of stochasticity and can now say with confidence that the
> emulator is 100% deterministic.